# how to call a PHP web service from Node.js

Tags: php, web-services, node.js

how can i call a PHP web service from node.js . thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you define that PHP service a bit more? Is it a PHP-based service on a *different server, or PHP on the *same server? My answer would be very different for each case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [node-httpclient](https://github.com/billywhizz/node-httpclient) to perform get requets to any server, not necceserialy PHP.

```
var client = new httpcli.httpclient();  
var url = "http://domain.com/get/bananas"
client.perform(url, "GET", function(result) {
// Result is the response of the server
}, null);
```